# Optimizing mySQL database on large table with frequent writes and fulltext columns?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, innodb, myisam

My team runs a shopping information site and as we've started to grow, we're starting to experience issues with query response time on our product table impacting display speed.

The main issue we experience is when a user "saves" an item triggering an update query as other users are searching on the FULLTEXT indexes that exist as well:

```
UPDATE product SET listed = listed+1 WHERE product_id = XX
```

For example, I just ran the update in 0.01 seconds with no other queries hitting but a few minutes ago, with a large FULLTEXT request also going, the same request took 23 seconds.

I assume this is because the table is MYISAM and can't do row-level locks.

Our product table contains over 3.5 million records and will double by the end of the month. After that it should level off to 2-5% monthly increases.

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    product_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    category_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    title VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    short_desc VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    msrp DECIMAL (6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '000.00',
    rating DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0',
    reviews INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    listed INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    sku VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    upc VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    updateddate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id),
    KEY title (title),
    KEY category_id (category_id),  
    KEY listed (listed),
    KEY mfrg_id (mfrg_id),
    KEY identifier (identifier),
    FULLTEXT INDEX (title),
    FULLTEXT INDEX (description)
) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

The database runs on a dedicated server that only hosts our site. We are planning to move the database into a replication structure with a Dual Proc, 16gb RAM server for the query box [slave] and the current "web" server handling the writes [dual proc, 4gb ram].

I'm not DB expert [clearly] and from researching have become warry of running InnoDB at the same time as MYISAM [replication & backup implications?] but it does seem like splitting the product table to house main information [innodb] and the fulltext descriptions [myisam] seperately may help dramatically?

If you have an idea and need more info please comment and I will provide back more details.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exact about MyIsam. It's table-lock instead of row-lock like innoDB.

So from what you say, the query (full text) is taking a lot of time, so the update need to wait before being done.

You should really consider to switch to innoDB ( easy solution ) or switch your full text search to somewhere else like solr , elastic search, sphinx.

Also, you should check your slow_query log and optimize all those query.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Do you have any thoughts on breaking things out into two tables, myisam and innodb type respectively?

Comment: depend on a lot of thing, time - experience - money. One of the easiest way should move your full text field to another table. So when you will do your "slow search" you will still be able to update your source table. 7M rows within a MyISAM fulltext seems a lot of data i think.

Comment: Guess we're looking into Sphinx again. Any particular thoughts on the setup in relation to that? Just one table for products with it building off of the key fields or still a reason to split things out into two [innodb] tables?

Comment: i will not discuss about this into comments. If you remove MyISAM you will lost your fulltext search, so you will need to find another solution for this like Sphinx.